# Rgba value is not updated in ng-style

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change, ng-style

I have a div which has an ng-style attribute with an rgba value that uses a $scope variable for the alpha value:

```
ng-style="{'background-color': 'rgba(255,0,0,{{ alphaValue / 100}})'}"
```

I have an input slider which changes the value of alphaValue. I can see the change of the value using the console.log and the rgba value is being updated in the debugger in the html. It is just not being applied in the view.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using - `ng-style="{'background-color': 'rgba(255,0,0,alphaValue / 100)'}"`

Comment: no that won't work, you need the {{ }} to read the alphavalue.

Comment: remove {{}} from around alphaValue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would simply look like below

```
ng-style="{'background-color': 'rgba(255,0,0,'+ (alphaValue/ 100) +')'}"
```

Comment: @SilvioTroia If you look at [`ngStyle`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngStyle.js#L55) API, you will see that there is an $watcher placed over attribute value, and watcher always need `expression` not `{{}}`(interpolated value)

Answer (score 3):

Create a controller method get the style object. Its cleaner approach.

**HTML**

```
ng-style="ctrl.getElementStyle(alphaValue)"
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
 ctrl.getElementStyle = function (alphaValue) {
        var alpha = alphaValue / 100;
        return {'background': 'rgba(255,0,0,' + alpha +')'};
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you will need to resort to using a controller method:

```
$scope.getRGBA = function(alpha){              
   return 'rgba(255,0,0,'+ alpha / 100 + ')';
}
```

HTML

```
ng-style="{'background-color':  getRGBA (alphaValue)}"
```

Should make sure `alpha` isn't undefined also and set a default